# How to distribute the load on server over the entire day from my android app

Tags: android, api, server, android-intentservice

My app has the feature to send a particular app data to a server once a day in every 24 hr.
Total number of my Android app installs on play store  - 5,00,000 (approx)
Total no of seconds in 24 hr - 86400 sec.

I need to distribute the load on server over the entire day, in order to assure that all the installed apps are not sending data at the same time or in a short time window. 
In short I need some logic on client side to distribute these calls to server evenly across 86400 sec.

Comment: I don't understand the logic.. Your app send SMS to your server and what your server is doing with this SMS? send it to another user?

Comment: each client could be assigned a time slot by the server when they contact the server first time.

Answer (score 0):

A random number should give you enough spread with so many installs. So, first time app runs, call Rand(0, 86399), and save it in preferences. Then send sms at that second in day.

Comment: It's not that easy though. How will you schedule the action to send the sms? If you use an alarm chances are good there will be spikes again as they won't fire e.g. during doze but when the device wakes up again in the morning hours.
Enforcing the device to wake up is a quite rough thing just to fire an event that doesn't seem to be time relevant.

Comment: An easy hack is to use only half the seconds (43200), and add it to 9am local time. Should still give enough spread, especially if you have users in multiple time zones.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar situation, and we switched this type of call from Apache server to node.js server, and never looked back. Node.js can handle many many more connections AND can return and close connection before all the work is done (so for example if data is not critical, you can close connection and return, before saving to database).